# How to make a google-like auto complete textbox with C# in a WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, autocomplete, textbox

I tried to find a solution but I didn't found what I was searching for. So here is my problem.
I want a google like behaviour with a textbox. As I type "dum" it should find dummy in the database and display it as option under the textbox. It should be selectable.
I don't use ASP.net or any other stuff. Just pure C#.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you don't use ASP.Net or any other stuff, you don't have any UI at all.  You're probably using WinForms.

Comment: Sorry... what I am using is WPF Application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the [`AutoCompleteSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletesource.aspx) property to a list of strings, and set [`AutoCompleteSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletesource.aspx) to `CustomSource` and [`AutoCompleteMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletesource.aspx) to `Suggest`.

Comment: This might give a preformance problem if there are a lot of entries in the database. I doubt Google uses this technique. I think they make a new query to load new suggestions on the fly every time you press a key.

Comment: I guess for my needs this solution totally fits my needs. ;) Thanks SLaks and Mark Byers.

Comment: @Mark: Google doesn't use WinForms.  It would be impossible for Google to do something similar because the the sheer volume of their suggestions (millions? billions?)

Comment: @MarkByers I thought the question was referring to WPF and not Winforms. Will this answer work in WPF ?

Answer (score 6):

Check these ones out:

- [Create an AutoComplete TextBox Control in C#](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/index.php?showtopic=34785)
- [AutoComplete TextBox](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/AutoCompleteTextBox.aspx)
- [AutoComplete From Database](http://www.aspdotnetcodes.com/AutoComplete_From_Database.aspx)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

My solution:

```
private void tbautocomplete_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AutoCompleteStringCollection namecollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=88888;Initial Catalog=contrynames;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT  distinct(person_Firstname+''+person_Lastname) AS name FROM persondetails WHERE name Like '%'+@name+'%'";
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader rea = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (rea.HasRows == true)
    {
        while (rea.Read())
        namecollection.Add(rea["name"].ToString());            
    }
    rea.Close();

    tbautocomplete.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
    tbautocomplete.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
    tbautocomplete.AutoCompleteCustomSource = namecollection;
```

Answer (score 0):

For auto complete textbox at first take a textbox and a listbox with same width.Then create some event such as textchanged,previewtextKeydown,listbox selectionchanged.And u get your solution.
For more details please see this example 
[autocompleteTextBox](http://refat38.wordpress.com/2011/03/16/autosuggest-textbox-for-wpf/)